# perform filtering on autocomplete

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-cursoradapter

I have an autocomplete in which as I start typing I get displayed the content of two columns in a database.

Now,I wanna perfom a filtering on this and I implemented the following metod:

```
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) { return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint); }

            String filter="";
            if(constraint==null) filter="";

            else filter=constraint.toString();

          Cursor cursor=db.getCursor(filter);
          return cursor;
        }
```

The method in my class that manipulates the database looks like this:

```
 public Cursor getCursor(String prefix) {


        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();


        String[] args = {prefix};


        queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_2);


      String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] {"route","user_id"};


        Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(db,asColumnsToReturn,null, args, null, null,null);


        int idcol =  mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROUTE);

        int kwcol =  mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_USER_ID );


        while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {

            String id = mCursor.getString(idcol);

            String kw = mCursor.getString(kwcol);

            Log.d(id,kw);
        }

        return mCursor;
    }
```

Question:Why don't I get nothing displayed in my autocomplete???

This is how my logcat looks like:

```
05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366): An exception occured during performFiltering()!

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x3114b8

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_bind_string(Native Method)


05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:178)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.bindString(SQLiteQuery.java:190)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:55)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1220)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:316)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:266)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at com.server.DBAdapter.getCursor(DBAdapter.java:199)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at com.server.Server8$ContactListCursorAdapter.runQueryOnBackgroundThread(Server8.java:185)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.widget.CursorFilter.performFiltering(CursorFilter.java:49)
05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

05-01 09:28:59.207: WARN/Filter(366):     at 
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Answer (score 0):

try and call moveToFirst() before the while loop

```
mCursor.moveToFirst()
 while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
         String id = mCursor.getString(idcol);

        String kw = mCursor.getString(kwcol);

        Log.d(id,kw);
    }
```